# How to Design a Table for scoring system in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I have a table for my products in Cassandra. In this table I store the product name and seller name (there may be thousands of sellers) and score (Product score of the seller) so as following

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    product_name varchar,
    seller_name varchar,
    score    int,
    primary key (product_name, seller_name)
);
```

I need to update score in my code

```
UPDATE products SET score = 2 WHERE product_name = "iphone-7" AND seller_name = "jack" ;
```

Everything is fine, except for Select Query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name = "iphone-7" ORDER BY SCORE DESC;
```

I need to get products by score order But as you know, it is not possible to sort without score being the primary key But if I put the score in the primary key, it will be not possible to update it what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have two tables that cover your requirements. For example the second table could be

```
CREATE TABLE products_score
(
    product_name varchar,
    score    int,
    primary key (product_name, score)
);
```

so you populate both when writing and use the second one for ordering by score

Comment: My need is to have a list of products with the highest score and their sellers. For example, there may be thousands of sellers for a mobile product, each seller has received its own score for this product.

Comment: for example: row 1 -> product_name: iphone7- seller_name: jack- score: 5 / row 2 ->  product_name: iphone7- seller_name:alex - score:2

Comment: then you add seller_name to the index.     primary key (product_name, score, seller_name). there you can query like this: select * from table where product_name = 'x' order by score DESC, seller_name DESC